# jQuery validate only works once

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

The jQuery validate doesn't function when I try validating the form for the second time. Even if i click on any of the textboxes, i get the following error.

> Unable to get value of the property 'settings': object is null or undefined

```
<form id="myForm" action="">

     <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" />
     <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2" />

     <button id="submit" name="submit">   
     </button>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#myForm').validate({

        rules: {
            input1: "required",
            input2: "required",
            agree: "required"
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            MyFunction(); // i somehow believe the problem could be here, i have added the code below
        }
    });

function MyFunction() {

    var firstname = $('#input1').val();
    var lastname = $('#input2').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("AddCustomer", "MyController")',
        data: "{'FirstName': '" + firstname + "','LastName': '" + lastname + "'}",
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (msg) {

            $('#myDiv').html(msg);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });

}

</script>
```

Main View from where the partial view is called.

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    @Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") //the action calls the Partial View
</div>
```

The function works fine. However, is there anything I need to add so that the validate works the second time.

The `form` is simple with some textboxes and a submit button. The `form` is inside a partial view if that would make any difference.

Let me know if I need to add the HTML mark up as well. Though I think it's something to do with the `AJAX` post.

Comment: This error occurs only when you let the textbox empty? This validation is in realtime, during your digitation?

Comment: the validation works as expected the first time, but once i click the submit button and add data through the ajax call and then even if i click on any textbox, i get this error.

Comment: Yes, please show the HTML markup.  You're always expected to show enough code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Is there a reason you've put the code for `submitHandler` into an external function?  Does it work if you just put all the code into the `submitHandler`?

Comment: Why do you believe the error originates from that line?  The console should be telling you exactly which line is tripping the error.  Because `Unable to get value of the property 'settings'` makes little sense with the code you've shown.

Comment: my manager wanted it that way. besides will it make a difference. i  had to declare some variables and stuff so i thot it will be a good idea.

Comment: the error breaks in - `jquery.validate.min.js` file

Comment: It's working repeatedly for me in this demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/quyzu00h/  ~  Again, please show enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61517/discussion-between-user2322507-and-sparky).

Comment: Your `button` is working although, for a `button` element, I'd make sure to explicitly set the `type` attribute as `type="submit"`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not reloading the page after the ajax submission, try using the `resetForm` method provided by the plugin.  Although, I would expect this to work repeatedly without needing to do the form reset.  The error message also makes no sense with what you've shown us so far.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm/

Try this someplace like at the end of your `ajax` `success` function...

```
$('#myForm').validate().resetForm();
```

---

**EDIT**:

Using your code, I cannot reproduce the problem you describe:

http://jsfiddle.net/quyzu00h/3/

Comment: i have to try this, not much given in the link you provided. could u explain what it does?

Comment: @user2322507, it resets the validator object as if the page was freshly loaded... removes any error messages, etc.  However, it will not wipe out any values you may already have entered in the fields.